# How to determine if one of this value 2,4,8 is in (select accessID)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have three tables

**usersinformation**

```
userID    surname

---------   ----------

0001      |   Gideon

0002      |   mesaih

0003      |    Princess
```

**Posting table**

```
userID    postingID   posting     status

---------   ----------  ---------- ----------
0001      |   1  |  xxxxy          1,2

0002      |   2  |   yyyyyy        3,6

0003      |   3  |   zzzzzzz        1,6
```

**follows table**

```
userID   followerID   accessID     
---------   ----------  ---------- 
0002      |   0001  |    1         
0001      |   0002  |    3       
0003      |   0001  |     6
```

**note**

when user is posting i give him option to select those that can access(view) the post
and I store the accessID as a string seperated with comma
e.g    **3,5,4**

note the **3,5,4** mean someting

3 means friend

5 mean family and so on

before the post can be display it has to check if the user that want to view the post has been added with one of the  accessID in posting status , if so it will be displayed

all my codes below
please help

```
SELECT 
pt.content,
pt.date, 
pt.postingID, 
pt.dimg,
ui.surname,
ui.lastname, 
ui.userID 

FROM posting as pt

INNER JOIN usersinformation as ui
ON pt.userID = ui.userID 

WHERE pt.userID = '$f_ID' 
OR 
    pt.userID   IN (SELECT follows.userID  FROM follows 
WHERE follows.followerID = '$f_ID')
AND pt.status IN (SELECT follows.accessID 
FROM follows WHERE follows.followerID =    

pt.userID AND follows.userID = '$f_ID')

ORDER BY  pt.postingID DESC



 if user that post has add the viewer with one of the acessID in posting status
```

thanks for your help

Comment: *@Sheyviruz*, it is bad practice to concatenate meaningful values together in one field if you are later going to need to query against them.  I would suggest modifying your design if you can.

Comment: I agree with Linger.  Modify the design before continuing.  Table design should reflect how you are going to query the data.

Comment: You need to normalize your table structure, and then the problem essentially goes away. If you can't or won't, then look into [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)